# JOIN relación entre dos tablas!

Tags: sql

Tengo el siguiente programa:

```
SELECT "resource"."name" "EMPLEAT", "attendance"."name" "DATA", "attendance"."action" "ACCIO", "attendance"."action_desc" "MOTIU", "attendance"."sheet_id" "FULL", "hr_action_reason"."action_type" "MOTIU" 


FROM "public"."hr_attendance" "attendance", "public"."hr_employee" "employee", "public"."resource_resource" "resource", "public"."hr_action_reason" "hr_action_reason"


WHERE "attendance"."employee_id" = "employee"."id" AND "employee"."resource_id" = "resource"."id" AND "attendance"."action_desc" = "hr_action_reason"."id"

ORDER BY "DATA" DESC
```

básicamente el programa me muestra los datos de hr_action_reason.. Pero solo 3... los que estan vacios no.. Y creo que tiene que ver con que tiene relación con Attendance."action_desc"

Es decir si llamo a Action_desc me pone huecos blancos de todos... pero si llamo a hr_action_reason me salen solo los 3 que tienen algo..

Tengo que usar Join? Es posible?

Gracias

Comment: podiras poner como la estructura de tus tablas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según veo puedes hacer un `JOIN` con las tablas `attendance` y `employee`, con el campo `id` y `employee_id`. Otro `JOIN` con `employee` y `resource` con el campo `id` y `resource_id`, sobre las otras tablas podrías hacer un `LEFT JOIN` para que solo los que cumplan la condición muestren datos y los demás, se muestren vacíos.

Adjunto cómo quedaría:

```
SELECT "resource"."name" "EMPLEAT"
    , "attendance"."name" "DATA"
    , "attendance"."action" "ACCIO"
    , "attendance"."action_desc" "MOTIU"
    , "attendance"."sheet_id" "FULL"
    , "hr_action_reason"."action_type" "MOTIU" 
FROM "public"."hr_attendance" "attendance"
    inner join "public"."hr_employee" "employee"
        on "attendance"."employee_id" = "employee"."id"
    inner join "public"."resource_resource" "resource"
        on "employee"."resource_id" = "resource"."id"
    left join "public"."hr_action_reason" "hr_action_reason"
        on "attendance"."action_desc" = "hr_action_reason"."id"
```